# Will the match method of String in javascript affect the lastIndex property of the Regex with the globe identifier?

Tags: javascript, regex

I encountered a strange question when i used the match method of the String. Using the following code

```
var str2 = " aa bb cc",
    greg = /((\S)\2)/g;
greg.lastIndex = 2;
str2.match(greg);
console.log(greg.lastIndex);
```

In chrome,the result of output is 2,but in FF and IE it outputs 0.
What I am asking is if there is something offical or standard that can illustrate this question.
Thanks.

Comment: There is no reason to set a lastIndex before a global match, the matching starts at 0 in all the browsers and finds all the matches, no matter what you write to the lastIndex. If you want to begin a match at some index, match a substring.

Comment: @kennebec  Thank you for answer my question and I know that the lastIndex property doesn't affect the global match.But I wanna know that whether the lastIndex property of the global regex is reseted to zero  or not after the match method is excuted.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like WebKit is right and IE and FF are wrong.  From [ECMA-262 3rd Edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) 15.10.6.2:

> Let e be r's endIndex value.
>
> If the global property is true, set lastIndex to e.